# Why is one div not positioning beside another div?

Tags: html, css, web, position, css-float

I am creating a website but I am having some problems with positioning of the divs.
My `content div` is not positioning beside `navigation-bar div`, even though I am floating both of them left.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="title">
Sample Title
</div>


<div id="navigation-bar">
Home
<br>
<br>
Products
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div id="content">
content goes here
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is theme.css file

```
#title
{
color: black;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 250%;
padding: 2%;
width: 70%;
height: 10%;
border: 4px solid blue;
}

#navigation-bar
{
background-color: #606060;
width: 15%;
height: 70%;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 2%;
font-size: 80%;
border: 4px solid blue;
}

#content
{
border: 4px solid blue;
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 70%;
}
```

Problem is that the `navigation-bar div` and the `content div` wont position next to each other, instead `content div` is positioning itself below `navigation-bar div`.

Thanks.

Comment: i am so stupid, i forgot to add 'float: left' to my navigation-bar div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are using `float: left;` for `#navigation-bar`?

```
#navigation-bar
{
   background-color: #606060;
   width: 15%;
   height: 70%;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 2%;
   font-size: 80%;
   border: 4px solid blue;
   float: left; <--- Add this Here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a `float: left` to the `#navigation-bar`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8LCZ/)